# Not able to iterate with the received continuation token

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I am working on a code to get a batch of records from my cosmosDB .Here is the code snippet of the loop. The result is just fetching the first batch with the retrieved continuation token. I am looking for a way of getting the data retrieved and inserted into the the child container with the continuation token

```
$ContinuationToken=$null
do{

$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $accountName -Database $databaseName -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName   

$ParentData = get-CosmosDbDocument -CollectionId $ParentContainer -Context $cosmosDbContext -ResponseHeader ([ref] $ResponseHeader) -ContinuationToken $ContinuationToken -ErrorAction Stop | ConvertTo-Json

$continuationToken = $ParentData[$ParentData.Count -1]


 if($ParentData -ne $null){

   $continuationToken = Get-CosmosDbContinuationToken -ResponseHeader $ResponseHeader  |ConvertFrom-Json

    $solution =$ParentData |ConvertFrom-Json 


foreach($item in $solution){

    $document=$item |ConvertTo-Json
    $Partition=$item.category

    New-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $childContainername -DocumentBody $document -PartitionKey $Partition -Upsert $true -ErrorAction Stop
    $count++


            }
    }

 }

 while($continuationToken -ne $null)
'''
```

Comment: You initialized continuation token like `$ContinuationToken` (notice the upper case C) but later on you're assigning it to a variable like `$continuationToken` (notice the lower case c). Can you try by changing `$continuationToken` to `$ContinuationToken`?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concern, could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following script

```
$dbName="ToDoList"
$accountName="stancosmosdb"
$container="Items2"
$Total=@()
$ContinuationToken=$null
$context=New-CosmosDbContext -Account $accountName -Database $dbName -ResourceGroupName stan
$maxCount=5

#list all documents in the container
do{
 $responseHeader = $null
 $getCosmosDbDocumentParameters = @{
        Context =$context
        CollectionId = $container
        MaxItemCount = $maxCount
        ResponseHeader = ([ref] $responseHeader)
    }

  if ($continuationToken) {
        $getCosmosDbDocumentParameters.ContinuationToken = $continuationToken

    }   
 $docs=get-CosmosDbDocument @getCosmosDbDocumentParameters
 $Total+=$docs
 $ContinuationToken= Get-CosmosDbContinuationToken -ResponseHeader $responseHeader
}
while($ContinuationToken -ne $null)

#add theses documents to the new container
foreach($item in $Total){

   $document=$item |ConvertTo-Json
   $document
   #insert
}
```

[image]